# Open sqlite database failed 

Tags: android

I put my sqlite database file in the "assets" folder And i write a DAO calss to get data from database,But the information from log.e means i can not open the database.

public class GetData {

```
 private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.SGMalls/databases/mallMapv2.sqlite";

private static SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

public static ArrayList<Mall> getMall(){

   ArrayList<Mall> mallArrayList=new ArrayList<Mall>();

    String queryString="select id,title from malls order by title";

    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH,      null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    Cursor cursor=myDataBase.rawQuery(queryString, null);

  if(cursor!=null){

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while(!cursor.isLast()){

     Mall mall=new Mall();

     mall.setMallid(cursor.getInt(0));

     mall.setMallname(cursor.getString(1));            
    mallArrayList.add(mall);
cursor.moveToNext();
   } }
 myDataBase.close();

 return mallArrayList;

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assets/` folder has nothing to do with databases, directly. If you put a database in the `assets/` folder, you need to copy it from the `assets/` folder to where you want the database to reside in the actual filesystem.

Comment: Thanks very much. So if i copy the database to sdcard. Then field path 
also is /data/data/com.SGMalls/databases/mallMapv2.sqlite"?
Thanks you

Comment: I mean i just set the copy path is :/data/data/com.SGMalls/databases/mallMapv2.sqlite"
Then this file is store in where? embed in this app?
I am sorry. I am  a newbie about android development.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) .

You will have to call first `createDataBase()` method. If `createDataBase()` runs successfully, you can check your `/data/data/com.SGMalls/databases/mallMapv2.sqlite` is really present.

If it exists already, it won't do any harm to it.

`copyDataBase()` should give you some explanations about how it does to copy from assets to ../databases/..